# Nextjs TypeError: Class constructor call cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Component } from 'react'

class call extends Component {
  callApi = () => {
    const result = axios.get(
      'http://localhost:5000/public/api/DCqHe6S4hPD3TqAsF3YjueAAagVvZF.php?password='
    )
    console.log(result.status)
  }
}
export default call
```

I don't understand what part I missed.
How can I fix it?

Comment: All React components should start with a capital letter. Apart from that  `render` method is missing from your component

Comment: A side note: most likely you're console.log will log nothing, as it will execute before axios received the data.